# Trouble setting css right property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have made a simple tooltip generator using JQuery 1.10.2 that reads the element's `title` value.

It's working okay, apart from if the element is to the right of the screen, sometimes the tooltip floats off the edge of the page.

If the element is near the right of the page, I'd like to positioning it somewhere close to the right-edge of the element.

My code is below, and also a JSFiddle.  All input appreciated!

```
function BuildTipsV3() {
    var tt = $("#ttfloat");
    $("[title]").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            // set tooltip
            var o = $(this).offset();
            var y = o.top;
            var x = o.left;
            var tooltip = $(this).attr('title') || $(this).data('title');
            $(this).attr('title', '');
            $(this).data('title', tooltip);
            tooltip = tooltip.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br/>");
            tt.html(tooltip);
            // position tooltip and show
            var ttRightSide = x + tt.width();
            if (ttRightSide < $(window).width()) { 
                tt.css({ top: (y + 15), left: (x + 5) });
            } else { 
                tt.css({ top: y, right: 0 }); // <-- problem (right:0) doesn't work
            }
            tt.show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $("#ttfloat").hide();
            $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('title')); // reset for accessibility
        }
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HSfHD/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HSfHD/17/)

You just need to reset the `left` and `right` styles when you're not using them:

```
if (ttRightSide < $(window).width()) {
    tt.css({
        top: (y + 15),
        left: (x + 5),
        right:'auto'
    });
} else {
    tt.css({
        top: y + 15,
        right: 0,
        left:'auto'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you hover on the *left* element it sets the CSS `left` but when you hover on the *right* element you only set the CSS `right` property, so the final style will have both `left` and `right` set.

You need to reset the `left` back to its default value first (and probably the same for the other properties), for example [**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HSfHD/20/) where I have added the following code:

```
if (ttRightSide < $(window).width()) {
    tt.css({
        top: (y + 15),
        right: 'auto',
        left: (x + 5)
    });
} else {
    tt.css({
        top: y + 15,
        right: 0,
        left: 'auto'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the left instead.

```
tt.css({
    top: y+20,
    left: $(window).width() - tt.width() - 20
});
```